# почему не выводит нужные списки с квадратом и кубом из чисел?

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

задание: дан список чисел, выведите список квадратов чисел из первого списка и список кубов чисел из первого списка с использованием lambda функций. мой код:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x*x, a)))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x*x*x, a)))
```

выводит две копии начального списка:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

почему?

Comment: потому что вы неверно применяете функцию filter (она тут вообще не нужна). достаточно просто сделать `print([x*x for x in a])` и всё. filter отфильтрует элементы списка, которые не соответствуют условию в вашей лямбда-функции. а вы написали такое условие, что ему соответствуют все элементы. вот вы их и получили.

Comment: А что вы здесь фильтруете? Вам же надо что-то сформировать новое. Замените `filter` на `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Если принципиально нужна lambda функция, то делается так:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
square_numbers = list(map(lambda x: x * x, numbers))
cubes_numbers = list(map(lambda x: x ** 3, numbers))
print(square_numbers)  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
print(cubes_numbers)  # [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```

Вместо filter применяется map, которая перебирает поэлементно список чисел и передает каждое число как входной параметр функции lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы некорректно используете `filter()`. Эта функция фильтрует итерируемый объект по какому-то условию. В вашем случае, вам нужна не фильтрация, а применение функции к каждому элементу объекта. Для этого необходима функция `map()`

То есть просто нужно заменить `filter()` на `map()`:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(list(map(lambda x: x*x, a)))
print(list(map(lambda x: x*x*x, a)))
```

Результат:

```py
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```